# Maven : How to deploy tar.gz files to nexus

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I currently have a tar.gz generated by running following command. I am generating tar.gz using maven-antrun-plugin.

```
mvn clean install
```

Configured the following in pom.xml

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.deploy.version}</version>
            <configuration>
               <packaging>tgz</packaging>
                 <!--<artifact>${project.groupId}:${project.name}:"tar.gz":${project.version}</artifact>-->
                <!--<attachedArtifacts>sa-${project.name}-${project.version}.tar.gz</attachedArtifacts>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Can someone help me how to deploy tar.gz to nexus if I run

```
mvn clean deploy
```

Comment: Do not use maven-antrun-plugin. Use maven-assembly-plugin and than you can simply do a `mvn deploy` and also it is not necessary to add particular configuration to maven-deploy-plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I can't use assembly plugin because of it is not meeting my requirements. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It is exactly for your requirements. I can create a tar.gz / tgz file and it will be (correctly configured) automatically deploy the created tar.gz in one go...Furthermore the maven-deploy-plugin does not have a configuration which is named `packaging`...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/

With that you can define a file which should be uploaded:
https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/upload-single-mojo.html